# Difference between these two "methods" for simple character encryption

Tags: java

I have trouble understanding this simple method for encrypting characters in a string. So here's the method:

```
encryptedChar = (char) (’A’ + (originalChar -’A’ + offset) % 26);
```

I don't understand the need for `'A' - 'A'` since they just cancel out. What is the reason behind it?

Why shouldn't I just use the following method?

```
encryptedChar = (char) ((originalChar + offset) % 26);
```

Shouldn't it work exactly the same?

Comment: Because there's a modulo `26`. They don't cancel out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
encryptedChar = (char) ('A' + (originalChar -'A' + offset) % 26);
```

The two 'A' don't cancel each other, since the second one is inside the expression that is the operand of the modulus operator.

- `'A' + (originalChar -'A' + offset) % 26` - here each letter is mapped to a different letter.
- `((originalChar + offset) % 26)` - here each letter is mapped to a character whose int value is between 0 and 25.